# Matlab: how to generate large number of samples

Tags: matlab

```
x = 10*rand(1,1e6);

n=100;
z = ((sum(x(1:n))-n*5)/std(x)*sqrt(n))*ones(1,1e6);


figure;
cdfplot(z)
```

So, for vector "z", I want every different numbers of 10,000 samples, when "x" is defined as sets of numbers between 0 to 10. However, if I implement my code, I can only get 10,000 same samples for "z". How can I create 10,000 different samples?

Comment: Please describe what you want to implement. The code is very strange. `n=1`, thus `x(1:n)` is `x(1)`. The `sum` is useless because it has only one input element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is the sum of `x` minus 500, divided the the standard deviation of `x` multiplied by 10, which will give a scalar which is then multiplied by a vector of ones. This will give you the same number repeated one million times.

Your question is very unclear so I am not sure what you want this code to do, however if you want to use 10,000 values between 0 and 10 to calculate each element of `z`, and you are going to calculate one million random numbers in total, then I think this is what you want:

```
x=10*rand(1e4,100);

n=100;
z=(sum(x)-5*n)./std(x)*sqrt(n);

cdfplot(z)
```

Comment: Thank you ! This was the right answer I wanted! Sorry for my unclear question, it was quite hard for me to describe clearly as English is not my first language.